# Python Interrupt attribute error

Tags: python, interrupt

Trying to learn interrupts by following RasPi.tv writeup http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio and I keep the error: "Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'wait_for_edge'"
This is just an intermediate step in my ultimate goal but the code was intended to watch pin 7 for button press then run a sequence of LED's. I've been over it a dozen times and read numerous pages and cant find my mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

I'm running Python 3 and RPi.GPIO 0.6.2

```
# Threaded call back functino testing - waits for button press to run
#     GPIOidentChase
# import required libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Define GPIO numbering sustem used
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#time dealy
x = .5

# Define pins as input or output
# Using GPIO.PUD_UP REQUIRES your GPIO port to be the hot side of the switch
# and pressing the button grounds the circuit - DO NOT CONNECT BUTTON
# TO POS VOLTAGE

GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(8, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(9, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

def my_callback(channel):
# Chase sequence
    n = 17
    GPIO.output(n, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(x)
    GPIO.output(n, GPIO.LOW)

    n = 18
    GPIO.output(n, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(x)
    GPIO.output(n, GPIO.LOW)

# Additional channels removed to keep post short
# Below is the problem spot...
try:
    print("BUTTON IS CONNECTED TO GPIO AND GROUND?")
    input("Press Enter to continue")
    print("Wating for button press")
    #GPIO.add_event_detect(7, GPIO.FALLING, callback=mycallback)
    #I've tried both add event detect and wait for edge with same result
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(7, GPIO.FALLING)
    print("PIN 7 Grounded, callback ran")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup() # GPIO cleanup on CTRL + C
    print("User Stopped")

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup() # GPIO cleanup on normal exit
```

Comment: Did you, by any chance, name the file gpio.py? Try renaming it.

Comment: By the way: don't “GPIO cleanup on CTRL + C" since the ˋfinally` clause is always called.

Comment: Name is GPIOidentChaseButton.py and Thanks for the heads up on the 'finally' cleanup, simpler is always better for me.

Comment: I only had a small SD card on hand so I'm running a Wheezy distro, could that be part of the issue? If so is there an easy fix short of switching to Jessie?